# Handling Rest sql exception from client

Tags: android, spring-boot, exception, retrofit2

I an working with spring boot and android.

I am trying to create user using post. For positive conditions it's working fine, but in negative conditions such as primary key violation server throwing sql exception.

I want to show the error message "client user already exists"

Comment: Reworded, but needs further code from the original asker to be helpful.

Comment: I have not implemented I have just implement normal post method I don't how to do, I just want to know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just mockup based on my code in production (sorry for using Kotlin, you may reformat if as Java):

1. Create uniformed Response format

```
data class Response @JsonCreator constructor (
    var message: String? = "",
    var success: Boolean = false,
    var data: Any? = null
)
```

2. Return as ResponseEntity<Response> inside Controller

```
@PostMapping
fun createUser(@ResponseBody newUser): ResponseEntity<Response> {
    return ResponseEntity(
        Response(
            "Create user: ",
            true,
            this.userService.createUser(newUser)
        ),
        HttpStatus.OK
    )
}
```

3. Create CustomException for throwing any undesired condition

```
class ResourceNotFoundException: RuntimeException {
    var statusCode: Int? = null

    constructor(errorMessage: String, statusCode:Int): super(errorMessage) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode
    }
    constructor(errorMessage: String, cause: Throwable, statusCode: Int): super(errorMessage, cause) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode
    }
}
```

4. Create user, if error throw above custom exception

```
fun createUser(newUser: UserEntity): Boolean { // can be replaced by any response
    try {
        this.userRepository.save(newUser)
    } catch (e: DuplicateKeyException) {
        throw ResourceNotFoundException(
            "Client user already exists",   // custom http message
            "404"  // custom http status
        )
    }
    return true
}
```

5. Catch the message and show it to user from Android

```
showToast(response.message)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried this but message field is empty in the response of retrofit

Comment: try using rest api client like postman or insomnia, if the message is shown, then check your retrofit code

Answer (score 1):

This is a validation check scenario not exception handling case. You need to add validation check:
-> first check in DB if user exists or not and if exists throw error.

We add validation check when where we get input from user.
We do exception handling when there is some possibility of error in code or trusted client (like our UI application logic where user input not involved).

For handling exception and throwing some message to client. We need to use `@ControllerAdvice`:
Tutorials : [exception-handling-with-controlleradvice](https://dzone.com/articles/global-exception-handling-with-controlleradvice)
Spring Docs : [exception handling in spring](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)